# How can i use click event in Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I use click event in `Selenium` and `C#`

For example:

1. Go to Google Homepage.
2. Search the result `Test`
3. Click on the Search button, page change.

How can I get the new page?

Code Screenshot link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/23ih019wuczp3uv/Screenshot%202018-05-07%2011.08.38.png?dl=0

```
 public void opengoogle()
    {
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.AddArgument("--headless");
        ChromeDriver wd = new ChromeDriver(option);
        try
        {

            wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Click();
            wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Clear();
            wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).SendKeys("Test");

        }
        finally {  }
```

Comment: Please paste your code, don't send screenshots of it.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: If I got question right, You can get html of  new page as string after button click by driver.PageSource.

Comment: Yes, how can I handle this with the single script?  @GiorgiChkhikvadze

Comment: Added the Code @DebanjanB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe the HTML the desired element identified through **`By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")`**, it is within a `<form>` tag. So once you have sent the *search text* within the *search field* you can invoke **`Submit()`** method as follows :

```
wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Click();
wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Clear();
wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).SendKeys("Test");
wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#lst-ib")).Submit();
```

Comment: How can i go to the new URL after that ?

Comment: @MssTester That seems to be a separate question all together. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: @MssTester Upvote the Answer if this/any answer is/was useful to you for the future readers.